# Global javascript variable and array of objects issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, global-variables

I have a variable:

```
var  sizes = [


 { girl_top: '<h1> GIRLS - TOP\'S REGULAR</h1>'+
'<table style="margin: 0px 0px 15px}, float: none}, font-family: Nunito, Arial, sans-serif}, width: auto}, border: 1px solid #cccccc}, text-align: center}, font-size: 14px}, color: #333333}, border-spacing: 0px}, font-weight: 400},">'+
'<tbody>'+
'<tr style="font-weight:bold">'+
'<th style="width: 216.2px},  text-transform: uppercase}, text-align: center}, border-right: 1px solid #cccccc}, padding: 1em 5px}," colspan="2" scope="col">SIZE</th>'+
'<th style="width: 217.8px},  text-transform: uppercase}, text-align: center}, border-right: 1px solid #cccccc}, padding: 1em 5px}," scope="col">AGE</th>'+
'<th style="width: 217.8px},  text-transform: uppercase}, text-align: center}, border-right: 1px solid #cccccc}, padding: 1em 5px}," scope="col">HEIGHT</th>'+
'<th style="width: 217.8px},  text-transform: uppercase}, text-align: center}, border-right: 1px solid #cccccc}, padding: 1em 5px}," scope="col">WEIGHT</th>'+
'<th style="width: 218.6px},  text-transform: uppercase}, text-align: center}, border-right: 1px solid #cccccc}, padding: 1em 5px}," scope="col">CHEST</th>'+
'<th style="width: 218.6px},  text-transform: uppercase}, text-align: center}, border-right: 1px solid #cccccc}, padding: 1em 5px}," scope="col">WAIST</th>'+
'</tr>'+
'<tr>'+ 
....
```

but this variable is recognizable as a global variable and I can't access using `sizes.girl_top`

Where I'm wrog? Anybody see any error in my code?

Comment: `sizes[0].girl_top`. It's an array of objects

Comment: no, I cant access to variable ...

Comment: What do you mean? `'sizes' is undefined`? Explain what's happening

Comment: my global variables are in /js/size.js file and they contain html code in string - stored in js variable... when I try to use it I cant access to global variable...

Answer (score 0):

sizes is an array.
you should do

```
sizes[0].girl_top
```

to access the attribute

because you have it in []
if you want access attribute with sizes.girl_top remove the '[' and ']' to convert the array into object

Comment: I said that in comments, and OP replied "No, I cant access to variable"

Comment: I can't use comments :/, need 50 rep

Comment: My point was, I _already_ said that in comments :)

Comment: Look under comments section what is written then.
"Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post."